# Nancy ClaimsPrinciple vs IUserIdentity

Tags: nuget, nancy

I'm using  Nancy and want to add forms authentication.  My Nancy version is 1.4.3, but on nuget I can only find Nancy.Authentication.Forms 1.4.1

In 1.4.3 and 1.4.1 IUserMapper is defined differently:

1.4.1 IUserIdentity GetUserFromIdentifier
1.4.3 ClaimsPrincipal GetUserFromIdentifier

Do I need to downgrade to Nancy 1.4.1, or is there some simpler way to make this work?  I'm happy to implenment IUserMapper, but need one definition!

Answer (score 2):

Stick with `ClaimsPrincipal` which is the new standard and will make your upgrade to 2.0 seemless as well.